# How to use a builder pattern with vargs?

Tags: java, builder

Suppose I have varargs method that I'm trying to build Foo that uses builder pattern

```
public Foo buildSomething(String... attributes) {
  return Foo.builder()
      .attribute(attributes[0])
      .attribute(attributes[1])
      .attribute(attributes[2])
      ...
      .build()
}
```

Obviously, this does not work. Can it be done with streams?

Comment: "What's the best way" questions are usually opinion-based, hence [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You're right. I revised my question

Comment: I vote to re-open this Question. The question is clear and specific. The question is asking for a strategy on handling a series of arguments with a builder.

Comment: What is the benefit of a Builder in this scenario? Passing the varargs param to the constructor of `Foo` would be more straight forward.

Comment: @jaco0646 'Foo' may not be something I wrote or can extend. In my case, `Foo` is part of another library

Comment: Are you asking about setting several *different* attributes? Like first name, last name, phone number, birthdate, on a class `Person `? Your example calling the same `attribute` method repeatedly has caused confusion, as you can seen the various comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder();
for (String attribute : attributes) {
    builder = builder.attribute(attribute);
}
return builder.build();
```

Calling `builder =` in the for loop is usually not necessary, but this way you don't make any assumptions about the builder returning the same instance or not.

You can do this with streams but I think it is unnecessary given the requirements:

```
FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder();
Arrays.stream(attributes)
        .forEach(builder::attribute);
return builder.build();
```

I would only recommend using streams if you need to use some of the other intermediate/filter methods. Otherwise you are probably creating unnecessary allocations. You are also unable to update/reassign the builder variable unless you use something like `AtomicReference` or a one-element array:

```
FooBuilder[] builder = {Foo.builder()};
Arrays.stream(attributes)
        .forEach(a -> {
            builder[0] = builder[0].attribute(a);
        });
return builder.build();
```

Yuck.

Comment: How does the `attribute` method know which attribute is which? Are you suggesting writing a builder class that tracks how many times the `attribute` method has been called? If so, I suggest explaining that in your Answer. And maybe give some example code.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to do it with streams?

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm assuming that "knowing which attribute is which" is not part of the requirements. I'm assuming that the `Foo` class simply has a `List<String> attributes`.

Comment: @kane I added an example of how to do this with streams.